# Product Special Price does not display in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I got an issue with this. Although I got the solution but I still want to know exactly why it catch that.
I have a Magento Site with desktop version and mobile version.
At the category page, it show a list of products as you've known. And now, there is a problem

I get the structure for each product like this:

```
Product Name
Image
Regular Price
Special Price
```

In mobile version is OK, but the desktop version does not have the Special Price.
I used to code

```
"$product->getSpecialPrice()"
```

to get it but not working.
The different of these versions just from the front-end, all of the functions from back-end are the same. Exactly, the product data is retrieved by the same function

```
getLoadedProductCollection()
```

of product list block of Magento Core. So, I really could not understand why I am able to get the value of Special Price by calling `$product->getSpecialPrice()` in Mobile version, but not in desktop.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on [magento.se]

Comment: Is this really belong on Magento? If it cause between 2 different products is OK, but here is between 2 different views of the only one product. Please tell me more, Mike. Many thanks about it. I really want to know exactly.

Comment: The function `$product->getSpecialPrice()` is independent of Mobile / Desktop version.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: yup, I guess so but I don't know where it is. I traced the code but they're the same either mobile or desktop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
include_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addStoreFilter();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($_productCollection);


$todayDate = date('m/d/y');
$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')+1, date('y'));
$tomorrowDate = date('m/d/y', $tomorrow);

$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $tomorrowDate),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
    ), 'left');

foreach($_productCollection as $_product){
    if($_product->getData('special_price')!=null){
        echo '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(75).'" alt="'.$_product->getName().'" /><br />';
        echo $_product->getName().'<br />';

    $specialPrice = $_product->getData('special_price');
    $orignalPrice = $_product->getData('price');
        echo number_format($specialPrice, 2)."<br/>";
        echo number_format($orignalPrice, 2)."<br/>";                    
        echo '<a href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/magento/checkout/cart/add?product='.$_product->getId().'&qty;=1">Add To Cart</a><br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi savan, thanks for your coding, but I want to know the reason why it is different between mobile and desktop version? It does not override any back-end code. So no need to call another function to get collection for product with special price here.

Answer (score 0):

Just use getFinalPrice instead of getSpecialPrice. :D